# Allowing website access only from a specific network

Tags: php, html, security, networking

I'm making a website that appeals to students at my school. I want to only allow access if the user is on the campus wifi or hardwire. Using PHP, how can I restrict access to people I am sure are on the campus internet?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to get a range of IP addresses and put them in a while list. You could then use the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] variable to check against the white list for access. Do it at the beginning of the page with something like this:

```
if(in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],$white_list)) {
  //allow execution code?
} else {
  exit;
}
```

Comment: @Eric : And don't forget to make that a function, else, you'll right the allowing script a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually done in the webserver configuration, which has the advantage of also working for images, but in theory you could put

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != '...')
    die();
```

in every of your PHP pages.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you need to get the range of IPs from your school's network admin.
Then from PHP:

```
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if(inRange($ip)) die();
else { ....
```

Now write inRange($ip) function to return true if the given ip is in the range. you can use explode function to get pieces of the ip to compare.. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's already been mentioned, but the 'right' way to do it is to specify the IP range in the setup of your webserver (IOW, don't do it in PHP)